# Is there an R function for sorting the column that comprising two conected elements?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to compare the edge similarity of two undirected networks and to list their shared edges. Thus I want to sort the edge list first. Since they are undirected networks, e.g.,

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("A B", "B A","C A"))

     x

1 A B

2 B A

3 C A
```

I want to sort the column to make it like

```
 x

1 A B

2 A B

3 A C
```

Is that possible? Or if there is a better alternative for this?

Comment: if the two networks are stored as `igraph` graphs, you can use `intersection` to get the edges present in both

Comment: Cool and thanks!! That is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

We split the 'x' by space (`' '`), `paste` the `sort`ed elements and assign it to column 'x'

```
df$x <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$x),  " "), 
           function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=' '))
df$x
#[1] "A B" "A B" "A C"
```

Comment: Thanks! But sorry I made some typos and please see my edited question description.

Comment: @ZQu  Based on the example you provided, it is working for me